# In SFML Why does my projectile slows as it gets closer to target

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating a small 2D top-down program that will have a projectile created when the left mouse is pressed. Then the projectile moves toward a goal. **My issue is that the projectile slows when it moves closer to the goal.** It should remain the same speed. I looked into normalize thinking that would help but have had a hard time finding much on SFML normalize. What I did find has not helped.

Here is my update for my projectile (agents):

```
void agent::update(const sf::CircleShape* goal, sf::Time delta) {
direction = goal->getPosition() - body.getPosition();
sf::Vector2f newPos = body.getPosition() + sf::Vector2f(direction.x * speed * delta.asSeconds(), direction.y * speed * delta.asSeconds());
body.setPosition(newPos);
}
```

ps. I have it in asSeconds instead of asMilliseconds or it goes weird and lags.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in sfml, but you probably need to convert the `direction` vector to a unit vector.  Currently the vector has a magnitude proportional to the distance between the objects.

Comment: That is what I did with normalizing the direction but no change. I could not find a normalize function for Vector2f so I wrote one.

Comment: What does your normalize function look like?  Also, I don't see it being used in the code above.

Comment: I did use it to normalize the direction right after `direction = goal->...` . `sf::Vector2f agent::normalize(sf::Vector2f vec){
 float mag = sqrt((vec.x*vec.x) + (vec.y*vec.y));
 float x = vec.x / (mag);
 float y = vec.y / (mag);
 return sf::Vector2f(x,y);
}`